# Angular2 animation, show label for X amount of seconds

Tags: animation, angular, angular2-animation

How can I use the angular2 animations to show a label for X amount of seconds? Ideally I would like to show a `saved!` label next to my input box which would fade in and stay for 2 seconds, then fade out. I can easily make the animation fade it, but how can I make it fade out?

Here is my animation:

```
animations: [
    trigger('hasSaved', [
        state('inactive', style({
            opacity: 0
        })),
        state('active', style({
            opacity: 1
        })),
        transition('inactive => active', [
            animate(500)
        ])
    ])
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/yfSdg1qoYz3oHzLWfG1U?p=preview**

You can use *ngIf and **`setTimeout`** together to achieve it.

I'm using **`keyframes`** to add animation.

```
animations: [
  trigger('hasSaved', [
    transition('void => *', [
      animate(1000, keyframes([
        style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-10%)',     offset: 0}),
        style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(-40px)', offset: 0.3}),
        style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)',  offset: 1.0})
      ]))
    ]),
    transition('* => void', [
      animate(1000, keyframes([
        style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)',     offset: 0}),
        style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(30px)', offset: 0.3}),
        style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(20%)',  offset: 1.0})
      ]))
    ])
  ])
]
```

---

```
export class App {
  showSave:boolean=false;
  title = 'app works!';

  save(){
     this.showSave=!this.showSave;  
      setTimeout(()=>{
         this.showSave=!this.showSave;  
      },2000)

  }
}
```